# Ionic / Cordova - cli commands in deep - build, compile, run, prepare

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Can anybody explain me what is the real difference between these commands and what they specifically do:

```
cordova build

cordova run

cordova compile

cordova prepare
```

Reading from the doc doesn't help much https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/#link-5

I have doubts because, for example, the command `build` and the command `run` both seems to build the app...

Comment: The build command is shorthand for prepare (checks files) + compile(creates final app). The command run does the build and executes the emulator/device

Comment: best thing you can do is to use the ```--help``` param with each command and it will give you more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order should be prepare -> compile -> build -> run. You can read in reverse second time to understand it better.

**cordova run**
- If you have already build the app, it simply runs. if you have not built the app then cordova will first build it and then run it. You cannot run a native app if it is not built (unlike web apps in browser).

**cordova build**
- Before you run you must build. As cordova supports multiple platforms you may specify iOS as target for the build phase. during build phase the necessary packaging is done for the targeted platform.

**cordova compile**
- A compile command is meant to check if your written code is perfect and no syntax error (or a reference error) exists.

**cordova prepare**
- A prepare is the phase before compilation. As cordova need to first convert your code to target the specific (iOS/android) platform, sometime a few developers optimize their code by first writing the code which is common for all platforms and then choosing prepare and writing platform specific code for iOS or Android for their ease. This step is also done in a situation when you do not find a good solution in cordova and want to write your own code to glue natively in platform.

Comment: thank you this is a good explanation, i will wait for better answers, if none i will accept your! thanks!

Comment: While I want to say this is a good explanation, I don't think it accurately describes what happens, and most of which seems to be written based on the common definition of these terms.

For example, if you `cordova run`, even if you just built, it will STILL build the app. @Sailen's comment answer is the most correct.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova has two separate phases in it's build process, [`Prepare`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-prepare-command) and [`Compile`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-compile-command).

**Prepare** basically copies the `www` folder into the platform specified, and any additional platform steps needed.

**Compile** will compile the app into a binary, (apk for android, .app for ios, etc)

The other commands are simply shortcuts for joining commands. The reason it is split out so much is so you can make hooks into before/after each step, if you need to run any custom code.

**Build** will run the the `Prepare` and `Compile` steps for you, since this is the most common usecase.

**Run** will call `build` before installing the finished app (and launching the emulator if `--device` wasn't specified). Looking at their docs I just learned you can `run --nobuild` to skip the build step!

Reading their docs was actually really helpful, so I would recommend doing that as well. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.htm